# Repeated NAK seem to overwrite payload

Tags: usb, windows-ce, driver

I'm new to driver programming in general and also to USB. However, I managed to write a driver for Windows CE (6.0) and I also had access to an USB-Sniffer to read all traffic between the host and the device.

The problem now occurs on some boards (2 out of the 3 I have):
When the device has no data to send and I issue an Interrupt-In-Transfer the device sends an ACK.

So far this is expected. However, something (I guess either the USB-Controller or WinCE) seems to automatically issue more IN-Transfers (3 on one board, 4 on another) and I get subsequent ACK. This isn't a problem so far either.

But the next IN-Transfer will also result in an ACK, no matter if there is data to send or not, I receive zero bytes in the driver.

Yet, when I look at the USB-Sniffer the proper telegram was send, however 2 more IN-Transfers are automatically issued and are responded with an ACK. So it seems like the data is overwritten by the ACK.

I tried everything that came to my mind so far: Reset the pipe, close and reopen the connection, but nothing seems to work out properly. Resetting the Pipe solves the problem in about half of the cases though. I really ran out of ideas for solving the problem.

Is there a way to tell the USB-Controller (or WinCE or whatever causes this behaviour) to always only issue one single transfer?

**EDIT**

Turns out it was a threading issue. Unfortunately I wasn't the one who fixed it and I have no access to the working solution, thus I cannot give further details.